# Taking input in python for two different test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing issue in taking different test cases in python

- test case-1: I have to take two strings in a different line
- test case-2: I have to take two strings in a same line

If I am writing code to first test case the second test case not executed and if I am writing code to the second test case the first test case not executed.

I tried in c/c++14 the both test cases are taking perfectly without any error, but in python 3.7 it shows error

This is for test-case-1

```
s1=input()
s2=input()
```

This is for test-case-2

```
s1,s2=input().split()
```

How can I write code for both test cases to get satisfy

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the error from trying to unpack too few elements, and ask for another input:

```
def get_inputs():
    s1 = input()
    try:
        s1, s2 = s1.split()
    except ValueError:
        s2 = input()
    return s1, s2
```